# PHP error after one click update

Tags: php, error, updates

I updated Craft to version 2.6.2798.

Since then I'm getting a PHP error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /craft/app/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType.php on line 428
```

PHP version on the server is 5.53.

Any ideas to fix that issue?

Comment: "PHP version on the server is 5.53." You sure about that?  That error is a bug in Craft (just fixed for the next release) that indicates you're probably running PHP 5.3.x.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in [Craft 2.6.2804](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2804).

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same issue, not sure what PHP version i'm on though. It is possible to access the login screen, but after getting redirected to the dashboard it shows a HTTP 500 error message and with 'devmode on' it gives me this same error on whatever page off my site I try to access.

EDIT: Ok, this may be a bit of a radical solution, but I just deleted the following on line 428 in the file:

```
    'criteria' => [
        'locale' => $targetLocale
    ],
```

At least everything is working again... But a more substantiated solution would be nice ;)

Comment: Looks like some PHP 5.4 syntax got into the release. We’ll get an update out ASAP that fixes this. Deleting these lines works, or changing `[` to `array(` and `]` to `)`.