# My site is down and I can't access the admin panel after attempting an automatic update

Tags: updating

I attempted to update my website by pressing the update button in the control panel. It failed and now site is down. How do I fix this? I don't have a backup to restore.

Comment: Craft creates a database backup when it initializes the update process and stores it in the `craft/storage/backups` folder.  Are you able to grab the backup from that location?

Comment: yes i have found the backup file now - just not sure what to do next ... i think i should delete the existing database and upload the backup one... then do i also need to upload new craft/app files? where can i get these from?

Comment: i'm a bit worried as the current database is almost 30mb and the backup is 8mb ...

Comment: Can you get access to the admin area at all? Even though your site is offline you should still be able to get access to the control panel

Comment: Answer here: [PHP error after one click update](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16098/php-error-after-one-click-update)

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in [Craft 2.6.2804](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2804).